# Probability with current chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I have this chain.

[image]

$A,B,C,D,E $ are switches. They are independent from each other. They can be switched on with probability $p$  or switched off with probability $1-p$. We need to find probability that when current get into the chain it will get out of the chain.

So I was thinking in to ways. Not sure which one is correct if it is so.

First way.  We have 4 possibilities to get out from the chain: $AB, AED, CD, CEB$ $$p^2+p^3+p^2+p^2=2p^2(1+p)$$

Second way. $$\mathbb{P}\big(       (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap E\cap D) \cup (C\cap D) \cup(C \cap E \cap B)         \big)$$ but here I have another problem. I know that $\mathbb{P}(X \cup Y)=\mathbb{P}(X)+\mathbb{P}(Y)-\mathbb{P}(X\cap Y)$ but when I try to apply I always loose something and cannot find right probability....

So which way is correct?

Comment: You can't add probabilities that way...it's possible that multiple pathways are open.  Note that if $p=1$ your answer is an unphysical $4$.

Comment: I think the number of combinations blocking current is rather smaller than the number of combinations allowing it.  So, I would suggest calculating $P'$, the probability that current *can't* get out.  Then your result $P = 1-P'$.

Comment: Is it possible to get $$\frac{1}{2}p^2+\frac{1}{3}p^3$$?